# Odoo POS ticket, large size with empty spaces

Tags: printing, odoo

I'm using Odoo v9. I'm facing some problems with the POS module. At the time of printing a ticket every thing is shown properly, but for some reason there is a large empty space, before the content of the ticket an after it, wasting 2/3 of all the space.

I'm just using odoo and an EPSON TV88 printer, I'm not using the posbox. I guess it is a configuration problem.

Comment: I think you need to add some context. Maybe include your configuration.  Maybe read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove extra space by reducing size of ticket from .xml file where ypu define template of receipt else you can also manage size from odoo. This located here:

> Settings>>Technical>>Reports>>Paper Format

Also here you can create your own format also.